# I can't understand the relationship between desequality and the question solution.

Tags: probability

Given this question from my university exam

> The lifetime of an electronic device is a random variable of the type
>   $$ = \sum_{i=0}^{n}_$$
>
> with an average of 50 hours and a standard deviation of 20 hours.
>   Assuming a stock of 20 devices with lifetime independent, calculate
>    an approximation for the probability of using accumulated of 20
>    devices exceeds 1200 hours of use.

the solution written by professor was:

> $$
> P\left(\frac{y - n\cdot m}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} > \frac{1200-1000}{20\sqrt{20}} \right) = Q\left(\frac{10}{\sqrt{20}}\right) \\Q\left(\frac{10}{\sqrt{20}}\right) =1.27\%
> $$

But for me there's a problem, I can't understand this solution, I seek at my text book, but nothing clarify it to me.  I think that this solution somehow comes from this desequality

> $$
>  P(x \space\epsilon\space I) \leq \frac{E[f(x)]}{a}
> $$
>   where:
>   $$ f(x) \leq 0 \space\forall\space X \\
> and\space f(x)\geq a > 0 \space \forall \space x\space\epsilon I
> $$

But I can't make the liking between this theorem and the solution presented by professor. Could someone help me giving some clarification??

Answer (score 1):

The solution is using the property that
$$\sum_1^n N(\bar x, \sigma) = N(n\bar x, \sigma \sqrt{n} )$$

Hence, the probability distribution of the accumulation is basically $N(1000, 20\sqrt{20})$, and that has been used for the rest of the calculations

Comment: I don't know this property, my text book didn't mention it. Could give its  reference or this property name to I search in the web and study about it??